# Populating a List<t> in a pageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, realm

i have a `League` class which contain a list of matches. These matches i would like to populate into pageViewController. However i keep getting following error:
`Cannot invoke 'indexOf' with argument list of type (match)`. i guess this is due to the fact that `items` is of type League. However i've set `['matches']`so shouldnt this populate all matches? so how come i cant indexOf and why isnt it of type match?

**Variable**

```
var items: Results<League>?
```

**realm model**

```
class League:Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var name: String? = ""
    var matches = List<Match>()


    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Match:Object {
    dynamic var matchId: Int = 0
    dynamic var date: NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var homeName: String? = ""
    dynamic var awayName: String? = ""
    dynamic var homeAcro: String? = ""
    dynamic var awayAcro: String? = ""
    dynamic var awayScore: Int = 0
    dynamic var homeScore: Int = 0
    dynamic var leagueName: String? = ""
    dynamic var homeLogo: NSData = NSData()
    dynamic var awayLogo: NSData = NSData()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "matchId"
    }

}
```

**pageViewController delegate methods**

```
extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentText = (viewController as! ScoreViewController).match

        var currentIndex = items!["matches"].indexOf(currentText!)
        if currentIndex == items!["matches"].count - 1 {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(0)
        } else {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(++currentIndex!)
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentText = (viewController as! ScoreViewController).match
        var currentIndex = items!.indexOf(currentText!)
        if currentIndex == 0 {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(items!["matches"].count - 1)
        } else {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(--currentIndex!)
        }
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController {

        let contentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ScoreViewController") as! ScoreViewController
        contentViewController.match = self.items!["matches"][index]
        return contentViewController
    }







}
```

**Items initialized**

```
for (_, item) in result {


    if let leagueId = item["league"].int,
        let leagueName = item["name"].string,
        let allMatches = item["matches"].array {


            let leagueObject = League()
            leagueObject.name = leagueName
            leagueObject.id = leagueId



            for match in allMatches {
                if let matchId = match["matchId"].int,
                    let tournament = match["tournament"].string,
                    let homeTeam = match["homeName"].string,
                    let awayTeam = match["awayName"].string,
                    let homeScore = match["homeScore"].int,
                    let awayScore = match["awayScore"].int,
                    let homeLogo = match["homeLogo"].string,
                    let awayLogo = match["awayLogo"].string,
                    let date = match["date"].string,
                    let homeAcro = match["homeAcro"].string,
                    let awayAcro = match["awayAcro"].string{

                        if let awayLogoUrl = NSURL(string: awayLogo),
                            let homeLogoUrl = NSURL(string: homeLogo) {

                                if let awayLogoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: awayLogoUrl),
                                    let homeLogoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: homeLogoUrl) {

                                        let matchObject = Match()
                                        matchObject.matchId = matchId
                                        matchObject.leagueName = tournament
                                        matchObject.homeName = homeTeam
                                        matchObject.awayName = awayTeam
                                        matchObject.homeScore = homeScore
                                        matchObject.awayScore = awayScore
                                        matchObject.homeLogo = homeLogoData
                                        matchObject.awayLogo = awayLogoData
                                        matchObject.homeAcro = homeAcro
                                        matchObject.awayAcro = awayAcro


                                        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
                                        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")
                                        matchObject.date = formatter.dateFromString(date)!



                                        leagueObject.matches.append(matchObject)

                                }
                        }


                }






            }


            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(leagueObject, update: true)
            }


    }



}
```

Comment: Have you tried `items!.matches.indexOf(currentText!)` instead? `items!` isn't a dictionary according to your description.

Comment: yes but items has no member named `matches`

Comment: Can you show where `items` is initialized?

Comment: i've added it now, btw i'm using realm.io as database

Comment: the answer below shows your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `items` is `Results<League>` which doesn't allow taking a string as a subscript parameter. It should be giving you this error.

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'Results<League>' with an index of type 'String'
```

I think the main problem is that `Results<League>` is a collection of multiple leagues but your trying to treat it a single `League`.

---

Without knowing what your query is, you could use the first `League` in `items` like this.

```
let league = items!.first!
var currentIndex = league.matches.indexOf(currentText!)
```

But if you want a different `League` from `items` you can access them like this.

```
let league = items![number] // number can be anything in the range 0..<items.count
var currentIndex = league.matches.indexOf(currentText!)
```